# php array manipulation - transpose data

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data in this format in php:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
        (
    [A] => ID
    [B] => Name
    [C] => 2016/01/16 Qty
    [D] => 2016/01/16 Sales
    [E] => 2016/01/17 Qty
    [F] => 2016/01/17 Sales
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
    [A] => 1
    [B] => TestPrd1
    [C] => 1
    [D] => 2
    [E] => 3
    [F] => 4
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
    [A] => 2
    [B] => TestPrd2
    [C] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 7
    [F] => 8
        )
)
```

I want a function that modifies the array to be like this :

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
        (
    [A] => ID
    [B] => Name
    [C] => Qty
    [D] => Sales
    [E] => Date
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
    [A] => 1
    [B] => TestPrd1
    [C] => 1
    [D] => 2
    [E] => 2016/01/16
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
    [A] => 1
    [B] => TestPrd1
    [C] => 3
    [D] => 4
    [E] => 2016/01/17
        )
 [3] => Array
        (
    [A] => 2
    [B] => Testprd2
    [C] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 2016/01/16
        )
 [4] => Array
        (
    [A] => 2
    [B] => Testprd2
    [C] => 7
    [D] => 8
    [E] => 2016/01/17
        )
)
```

or to put it simple (first line containes headers):

ID,Name,2016/01/16 Qty,2016/01/16 Sales,2016/01/17 Qty,2016/01/17 Sales
1,TestPrd1,1,2,3,4
2,TestPrd2,5,6,7,8

to become :

ID,Name,Qty,Sales,Date
1,TestPrd1,1,2,2016/01/16
1,TestPrd1,3,4,2016/01/16
2,TestPrd2,5,6,2016/01/17
2,TestPrd2,7,8,2016/01/17

I have thousands of those rows (this is a very simplified subset of my data illustrating the problem), the aim is to read them from an excel file and get them into mysql.

Any ideas on what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: What is the pattern behind this and have you tried something? I don't see any logic behind this. Also see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Update description and data and provided another example

Comment: I still not 100% sure how you get from 2 rows to 4?

Comment: it is just that the data after the 2nd column are coming as columns instead of rows. so I have rows that have data by date (and date is the header). Obviously if I store them like this in my sql I will end up with two columns for every date and this will complicate things when I have 2 years worth of data in 730 columns..

Comment: So after the second column ever 2 columns are 1 new data set? Also what is the pattern behind the dates in the header column?

Comment: There is a system that produces an excel file. I process this excel file using IOFactory etc and read it in an array. After that I remove some headers and read in the above array the data.
I don't have the capability to produce the data in any other way, that is all I can get.
If for example I request data from 2016/01/01 to 2016/01/06, my header row will be :

ID,Name,2016/01/01 Qty,2016/01/01 Sales,2016/01/02 Qty,2016/01/02, Sales,2016/01/03 Qty,2016/01/03 Sales,2016/01/04 Qty,2016/01/04 Sales,2016/01/05 Qty,2016/01/05 Sales,2016/01/06 Qty,2016/01/06 Sales

I want  : ID,Name,Qty,Sales,Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Create a new array to hold data
$dataonlyarray = array();
$dataonlyarray2 = array();
$dataonlyarray3 = array();
$dataonlyarray4 = array();
// Start filling the new array with data
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($main_prod_arr); $i++) {
            $dataonlyarray2[] = array_slice($main_prod_arr[$i],0,$startingdatecolumn);
            $dataonlyarray3[] = array_slice($main_prod_arr[$i],0,$startingdatecolumn);          
            } 

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($main_prod_arr); $i++) {
            array_push($dataonlyarray2[$i],$main_prod_arr[$i][$startingdatecolumn]);    
            array_push($dataonlyarray2[$i],$main_prod_arr[$i][$startingdatecolumn]+1);
            array_push($dataonlyarray2[$i],$headers_arr[$startingdatecolumn]);          
            }   

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($main_prod_arr); $i++) {
            array_push($dataonlyarray3[$i],$main_prod_arr[$i][$startingdatecolumn]+2);
            array_push($dataonlyarray3[$i],$main_prod_arr[$i][$startingdatecolumn]+3);
            array_push($dataonlyarray3[$i],$headers_arr[$startingdatecolumn+3]);        
            }       

            $dataonlyarray4[] = array_merge($dataonlyarray2,$dataonlyarray3);
        array_push($dataonlyarray,$dataonlyarray4);
```